# Proxy Check in Java

Tags: java, url, proxy, connection

I try to check if a proxy is online or not. But everytime an Exception is thrown. I also tried it with System.setProperty (), but that doesn't work either...

My method:

```
public static boolean isOnline(String host, int port)
{
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    try
    {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
        connection.connect();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:484)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:482)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:481)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:522)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1146)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
at viewer.ProxyCheck.isOnline(ProxyCheck.java:18)
at viewer.Viewer.main(Viewer.java:7)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Seems like it isn't even trying to connect to the proxy! Have you tried to get the result of connection.usingProxy() to see if it actually tries to go by the proxy?

Comment: connection.usingProxy() returns false

Comment: On which exact line the exception is returned?

Comment: I just replace connection.connect () with connection.usingProxy() and return that boolean, it is false. No Exception was throw

Comment: Are you sure that the proxy you test is actually online?

Comment: Yes, every time before I tried, I checked the proxy in an online tool.

Comment: The question is can you actually reach this host from your own machine? Sometimes such problems can arise. Try to connect to that proxy and test it from, for example, your own browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isOnline(){
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "failProxyIP");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "failProxyPort");
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isOnline()); //prints false
}
```

Comment: Nearly the same exception, but now with "Unknown Source".

Comment: how to check if it needs username and password ?